# html agility pack - Object reference error

Tags: c#

I've been playing around with the htmlagiltypack for a few days, and I'm slowly starting to understand the logic behind scrapping data, however, I've run into an issue where I can't seem to see what's wrong with the code.

I'm trying to glean some data between a span tag, which has an attribute called itemprop, that has a value of 'genre'. I want to check one particular div to find all instances of this data.Here is my attempt:

```
 foreach(var item in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
     "//div[@class='infobar']/a/span[itemprop='genre']"))
 {
     newFilm.FilmGenre.Add(item.InnerHtml);
 }
```

I'm just not sure what i'm doing wrong :(

Comment: I would assume `document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes` returns `null`. Of course, simply firing up a debugger would have been the easiest way to see for sure.

Comment: In XPath, if you want to select from an attribute, you prefix it with a @ like it was done with the @class-definition in the beginning of your string.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I initially run the debugger and noticed that the output was, like you said, null. I then followed Karl's advice and added the @ before the attribute. I checked the debugger again and I noticed that innertext did hold the value I was looking for, however, I still get the following error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'